# How to join several tables consistently?

Tags: sql

How to join several tables consistently (Client -> User -> Order -> Product)?

```
SELECT Client.ID, Client.Name
FROM Client
INNER JOIN User ON Client.Created_by = User.ID
INNER JOIN Order ON User.ID = Order.Created_by
INNER JOIN Product ON = Order.Product_id = Product.ID
WHERE User.ID = ‘SomeUsername’ AND Product.Price > X;
```

The task is to select from the database customers created by the particular user and who at least once ordered a product more expensive than X USD amount.

Comment: what is the issue ? your query seems to be correct

Comment: What do you mean by "join consistently"? How does this query not perform as desired?

Comment: hi, you could use `where exists(...)` to filter for rows that match the constraint.

Comment: This line has an extra equal sign you need to remove: INNER JOIN Product ON = Order.Product_id = Product.ID

Comment: @mason there is a typo, I meant consequently Join Client On User On Order On Product

Comment: You appear to have written code to do that. Other than the extra equals sign mentioned, and the fancy quotes instead of proper single quotes in your question....what's not working with your approach?

Comment: @mason Glad to hear it, thank you. Actually I don't have a dataset to test it, it's sort of code on the paper.

Comment: So? Make a dataset. You can download any number of free RDMBS systems to verify, or use tools like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).